# Appharbor doesn't build anymore

Tags: asp.net, .net, appharbor

I pushed my .net project files to bitbucket and then bridge in appharbor site to the project on bitbucket. But it doesn't build after all as it used to. Is there anything that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Now I could make build it.

There is a sequence for the build process. First start a repo on bitbucket, and create an application on appharbor then push the project to the bitbucket repository. When you get back you will see your commit on bitbucket. Then click the deploy button over there.

It didn't use to need to push after bridging before.